Smoothness of a function is well-defined for functions between smooth manifolds
Definition: A function $F: M\rightarrow N$ smooth at $p\in M$ if there is a chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$, a chart $(V,\psi)$ about $F(p)$ such that $F(U) \subset V$ and the map $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U) \rightarrow \psi(V) $ is smooth at $\phi(p)$ in the usual sense.
I would like to see this definition is well defined: If $(U_1,\phi_1), (U_2,\phi_2)$ are charts about $p$ and $(V_1,\psi_1), (V_2, \psi_2)$ are charts about $F(p)$ such that $F(U_1) \subset V_1$ and $F(U_2) \subset V_2$, then  $\psi_1 \circ F \circ \phi_1^{-1}$ is smooth at $\phi_1(p)$ iff $\psi_2 \circ F \circ \phi_2^{-1}$ is smooth at $\phi_2(p)$!
To prove this, the usual trick is to write
$$ \psi_2 \circ F \circ \phi_2^{-1} = (\psi_2 \circ \psi_1^{-1}) \circ (\psi_1 \circ F \circ \phi_1^{-1} ) \circ (\phi_1\circ\phi_2^{-1})$$
and argue that the maps in $()$-brackets are smooth, this is easy to see. However, I'm concerned about the domains of these maps. Clearly, to have such a decomposition, we have to restricted the domain of definition to a smaller open set around $\phi_2(p)$. So let me do this: $\phi_1 \circ \phi_2^{-1}: \phi_2(U_1\cap U_2) \rightarrow \phi_1(U_1\cap U_2)$. Next,
$$(\psi_1 \circ F \circ \phi_1^{-1} ) : \phi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \rightarrow \psi_1(F(U_1 \cap U_2))$$
Now a problem arises is that, $\psi_1(F(U_1 \cap U_2))$ may not be open and so how can we talk about the differentiability of the map
$$ \psi_2 \circ \psi_1^{-1}: \psi_1(F(U_1\cap U_2)) \rightarrow \psi_2(V_2)$$
(the image should be $\psi_2(F(U_1\cap U_2))$ but it's not relevant here)?
If I am able to find an open neighborhood $O$ of $\psi_1(p)$ such that $O \subset \psi_1(F(U_1 \cap U_2))$ then I'm happy. However, what if $F(U_1\cap U_2)$ is a singleton? In this case, clearly we can not talk about differentiability of $\psi_2 \circ \psi_1^{-1}$, which is defined only at one point...
Thank you for your help!

Look at $\psi_1\circ F\circ\phi_1^{-1}$ as a map $\phi_1(U_1\cap U_2)\to\psi_1(V_1\cap V_2)$; this is a map between open subsets (of Banach spaces). You don’t restrict the target space to the image because the image is not open in general (e.g constant maps as you mentioned).

@peek-a-boo I'm still confused, so then how can the composition map be still smooth? Could you help me with this?

What’s the problem here? You have three maps ($\psi_2\circ\psi_1^{-1}, \psi_1\circ F\circ \phi_1^{-1}$ and  $\phi_1\circ\phi_2^{-1}$) between open sets all of which are smooth in the usual sense, and all compositions make sense, so the triple composition is smooth.

@peek-a-boo The part why we don't care about the images not open...

look, in multivariable calculus, we merely define the notion of smoothness in the following situation: $V,W$ Banach spaces, $A\subset V$ open and $f:A\to W$ a given map. Next, the chain rule (plus some induction) implies that if $A’\subset W$ is open and $X$ another Banach space and $g:A’\to X$ is smooth and $\text{image}(f)\subset A’$, then $g\circ f:A\to X$ is smooth. This statement does not care in the slightest whether $f$ is constant or $g$ is constant or whether their images are open or not. All we care is that $f,g$ have domains which are open and that the compositions make sense.

Oh I see now.... Thank you very much for your time!
